# mount cephfs or rbd via Internet

Tags: storage, internet, ceph

Is there any suitable solution for this?

I know about security issues, but is it possible?

Or other better storage solutions?

We tested `s3fs`+`cephrgw`, but It's very slow and unstable.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many security issues given that you use authentication for the stores. You can make your monitors public as well as the osds.